# How to change menu icon which is overriden (i.e. by WooCommerce)

Tags: functions, wp-admin, templates

How can I change the menu icon (coming from external plugins, like WooCommerce) in wp-admin area with custom icon? (The menu-item is actually `post-type`, so there should be some `register_post_type` command i think).

Answer (score 1):

WooCommerce styles the icon via this CSS file: `woocommerce/assets/css/menu.css`, and here's the corresponding code (*pretty-printed* or actually, I copied it from [`woocommerce/assets/css/menu.scss`](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/woocommerce/tags/3.4.3/assets/css/menu.scss#L17)):

```
#adminmenu #toplevel_page_woocommerce .menu-icon-generic div.wp-menu-image::before {
    font-family: 'WooCommerce' !important;
    content: '\e03d';
}
```

So you can change the `font-family` and the `content` (and other) properties to suit your custom icon.

---

Below is an example of customizing the icon by changing it to use a `background-image`:

```
// We hook to the `admin_enqueue_scripts` action with a priority of `11`, where
// at this point, the default CSS file should have been loaded. But you can or
// should add the CSS rule to your custom CSS file; just make sure it's loaded
// *after* the default CSS file.
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', function(){
    $css = <<<EOT
#adminmenu #toplevel_page_woocommerce .menu-icon-generic div.wp-menu-image::before {
    content: ' ';
    background: url('https://png.icons8.com/dusk/2x/e-commerce.png') no-repeat center;
    background-size: contain;
}
EOT;

    wp_add_inline_style( 'woocommerce_admin_menu_styles', $css );
}, 11 );
```

Note: The `menu.css` file is registered and queued in [`WC_Admin_Assets::admin_styles()`](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/woocommerce/tags/3.4.3/includes/admin/class-wc-admin-assets.php#L28) with the handle/name of `woocommerce_admin_menu_styles`.

Answer (score 0):

to add a custom image, you can use this code. the original image is set with CSS then you have to add custom CSS to remove that.

```
add_action("admin_menu", function () {

    foreach ($GLOBALS["menu"] as $position => $tab) {

        if ("woocommerce" === $tab["2"]) {
            $GLOBALS["menu"][$position][6] = "http://server/image.png";
            break;
        }

    }


});
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the custom icons are fonts files, How can I override it with it instead of image?